# position floating div under selection within viewport window

Tags: position, textselection

How do you position a floating div (i.e. position:absolute, e.g. dialog box) under text that has been selected while still showing the whole div within the viewport window even if the selection is at the edge?

Answer (score 0):

This solution using jQuery works for me. Please see [codePen](https://codepen.io/w-nema-the-builder/pen/LYrypGy) or below:

Javascript:

```
      const floater = $('<div class="floater"><div>^</div>You selected:<div class="selection">...</div></div>')
          .appendTo('body').show();              
  $('#selectable').on('mouseup', function (e) {
      const 
          selected = window.getSelection().toString(),
          half_floater_width = floater.width()/2,
          x = e.pageX;        
      if ( selected ) {
          let win_w = document.documentElement.clientWidth 
          floater.find('.selection').html(selected)
          if     ( half_floater_width + x > win_w ) floater.css({left:'auto', right:0     , top:e.pageY + 8})
          else if( x - half_floater_width < 0     ) floater.css({left:0     , right:'auto', top:e.pageY + 8})
          else floater.css(                    {left: x - half_floater_width, right:'auto', top:e.pageY + 8})
      }
  })
```

Html:

```
  <div id="selectable">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores mollitia amet laboriosam impedit aliquam, veniam
officiis porro quibusdam, expedita eligendi incidunt, rerum praesentium provident minus laborum. Deserunt illum non
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.floater {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 2px solid red;
  z-index:1;
  padding:20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  resize: both;
  overflow:auto;
}
```